# Share USB port over internet?

Tags: windows-7, macos, vnc, remote-access

I'm using TeamViewer to access my iMac (Snow Leopard) from my laptop (Windows 7) remotely. Is it possible to make Mac recognize my iPad as plugged in to a USB port on my laptop?

Are there any *free* programs that will do this?

EDIT:

A friend of mine mentioned network drive sharing. How would that work? Would it?

Comment: What kind of USB device are you talking about?

Comment: iPad. I have a laptop and want my iMac to behave as if the iPad is plugged into it when it's in fact plugged into my laptop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tools to redirect USB over Ethernet, like [**the one from Eltima**](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/). I used this to redirect a local USB port to a server accessed by Remote Desktop.

However this is a Windows-only solution, and I couldn't find such a program that works for both Mac and Windows.

Anway, even if it exists, I doubt it's free as it's pretty complex to code. All the similar programs to "USB over Ethernet" from Eltima I could find must be paid for.

Comment: A more user friendly software from the same company: [FlexiHub](http://www.flexihub.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will work even if you find a cross-platform USB over Ethernet software. Even USB HUBs sometimes cause syncing problems with Apples i-Devices where you have to restore the software through iTunes.

Comment: That probably has to do with powering issues and USB hubs, nothings to do with the concept of USB.